# How do I change "Done" to "Next" on the Android keyboard

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a few Entries on a view set up so that when I press "Done" on the keyboard it focuses the next Entry using this

`Entry0.Completed += (s, e) => Entry1.Focus();`

I'd like to make the keyboard say "Next" for Entry0 because it has a next entry to go to, and make the keyboard say "Done" for Entry1 because there is not entry to go to and the button dismisses the keyboard. How can I make this happen? Is there a way without custom renderers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a custom entry renderer (Must):

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/introduction/

and to change the text of the button (Android) you will have to use:

```
editText.ImeOptions = global::Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Next;
```

Where editText = Control from the EntryRenderer.

Comment: Disappointing but thanks. Seems every class I use needs a custom renderer for one thing or another...